# Proc_open read and parse output - real-time

Tags: php

When I run proc_open with a file.txt path for the stderr output, that file is constantly updated every couple seconds with output of the proc_open program I am running which is ffmpeg. I just want to redirect that output to a phpfile where it can be read and parsed but while the process is running (so send info every couple seconds) so I can update a database. IS this possible? **I have been googling for hours so if there are any experts out there who actually know how to use this function of have experience in this I would greatly appreciate any help.**

this puts output in a text doc. If I change to 2 => array("pipe","w") and the echo the output only comes on my screen at the end of the process

```
$descriptorspec = array(
0 => array("pipe","r"),
1 => array("pipe","w"),
2 => array("file","/home/g/Desktop/test.txt","a")
) ;

$cwd = './' ;
// open process /bin/sh
$process = proc_open("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/g/Desktop/vid.wmv /home/g/Desktop/vid.flv", $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you could run ffmpeg like this:

   ```
   ffmpeg ..optinons... 2>&1 | php script.php
   ```

But you could have in input STDERR and STDOUT of ffmpeg

1. And second normal decision:

   ```
   <?
   $cmd = 'ffmpeg -i /home/azat/Desktop/src.avi -y /home/azat/Desktop/dst.avi';
   $pipes = array();
   $descriptors = array(2 => array('file', '/tmp/atest.log', 'a'));

   $p = proc_open($cmd, $descriptors, $pipes);

   while (true) {
           sleep(1);

           $status = proc_get_status($p);
           if (!$status['running']) break;

           echo "STEEL RUN\n";
           // some manupulations with "/tmp/atest.log"
   }
   ```

Also you can see this [class](https://github.com/azat/akLib/blob/master/akExec/akExec.class.php) - it is a wrapper for exec processes

Comment: ffmpeg ..optinons... 2>&1 | php script.php if I do that, the php script will only execute once at the end. I want to keep sending info so I can create a progress bar. Your second suggestion will write to a log right? I want to be able to parse and send that information to a database on regular intervals. Can this be done? Also what does that class do?

Comment: Interval - is `sleep(1);`. Change it for your value. Class is do the same things, and even more (for example see `loop` method)

Comment: And about "ffmpeg ..optinons... 2>&1 | php script.php" you wrong! It will send output of ffmpeg to script while it comes from ffmpeg

Comment: Well I tried doing it and putting an insert statement in the script.php and only one database entry was there. I was expecting several. What variable do you use to refer to the ffmpeg data coming to script.php?

Comment: `$h = fopen('php://stdin', 'r'); $str = fgets($h); fclose($h);` `$str` - your string

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for pointing me in right direction. See my edit.